# Javascript ignore empty dropdown value

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying multiple ways to get a dropdown search function to exclude empty values. For example I have the following code with some blank lines (ie. value="") to allow each country group to be separate. The problem is that no matter what I do the page refreshes when I click on these empty values. I tried to exclude them using an if statement, but that didn't work. I can't just have it count as this content is loaded dynamically. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to Javascript.

Thanks!

```
<select id="state">
    <option value="">Select a State/Province to Search</option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="http://www.cabcot.com/listings/canada/">Canada</option>
            <option value="http://www.cabcot.com/listings/canada/manitoba/">  - Manitoba</option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="http://www.cabcot.com/listings/united-states/">United States</option>
        <option value="http://www.cabcot.com/listings/united-states/california/">  - California</option>
</select>

<script>
    document.getElementById("state").onchange = function() {
        if (this.selectedIndex!==0 && this.selectedIndex!=="" && this.selectedIndex!==null) {
            window.location.href = this.value;
        }        
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing `this.selectedIndex`, which will *never* be an empty string because its value is a number. Test `this.value` instead:

```
document.getElementById("state").onchange = function() {
    if (this.value != "") {
        window.location.href = this.value;
    }        
};
```